# How to change the style of fix field splitter for xamdatagrid(infragistics)?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am using Infragistics XamDataGrid to show my data, but the end user think the splitter is too wide which make them feel uncomfortable.

Wondering how to change the style of that splitter to make its width smaller.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/39797/255887.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I just tested using the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:FixedFieldSplitter}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="2"/>  
</Style>
```

The MinWidth property gets set to 7 by default so if you want a thinner splitter you will need to change the Width as well as the MinWidth in order to compensate or else your Width won't be allowed to go below 7.